# How to improve the quality(resolution) of the jfree chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Im using jfree chart(line chart) for my application... My chart looks blurry when created.. How can i get the high clarity image.

I have used: `ChartUtilities.writeScaledChartAsPNG(baos, chart, 205, 100, 4, 3);`

it doesnt works... Please suggest me any idea to do this.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
    final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                    "", // chart title
                    "", // domain axis label
                    "", // range axis label
                    categoryDataset, // data
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
                    false, // include legend
                    false, // tooltips
                    false // urls
            );

            chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
            final CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
            plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
            plot.setOutlineVisible(false);
            plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

            final CategoryAxis categoryAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
            categoryAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
            categoryAxis.setTickMarksVisible(false);
            categoryAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(2);
            categoryAxis.setTickLabelFont(ticklabelfont);

            final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
            rangeAxis.setVisible(false);
            rangeAxis.setRange(minRange, maxRange);
            rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(20));

            final LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
            categoryAxis.setTickLabelPaint(Color.decode("#222222"));
            if (lineColorFlag) {
                renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.5f));
            } else {
                chart.setPadding(new RectangleInsets(0, -8, 0, 0));
                renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.2f));
            }
            renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
            renderer.setBaseShapesFilled(true);
            renderer.setSeriesItemLabelsVisible(1, Boolean.TRUE);
            Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 6, 6);
            renderer.setSeriesShape(0, circle);
            renderer.setSeriesShape(1, null);
            renderer.setBaseItemLabelGenerator(new CustomLabelGenerator());
            renderer.setItemLabelAnchorOffset(-5);
            renderer.setBaseItemLabelsVisible(true);
            plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, Color.decode("#FEC240"));
            renderer.setBaseItemLabelFont(annotationlabelfont);
            plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, Color.WHITE);

            try {                      
    //            BufferedImage bi = chart.createBufferedImage(205, 100);            
    //            BufferedImage image = chart.createBufferedImage(205, 100);
    //            PngEncoder encoder = new PngEncoder(image, false, 0, 9);
    //            encoder.setDpi(300, 300);
    //            byte[] data = encoder.pngEncode();
    //            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    //            BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();            
ChartUtilities.writeScaledChartAsPNG(baos, chart, 205, 100, 4, 3);            
                byte[] bi=baos.toByteArray();
                InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bi);
                BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
                PngEncoder pngEncoder=new PngEncoder(bImageFromConvert);

    //            ChartUtilities.writeScaledChartAsPNG(baos, chart, 205, 100, 2, 2);
                ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "png", baos);
                byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
```

O/p image:

[image]

Comment: can you please add all the relevant code?

Comment: i have added my code @SteffenNieuwenhoven

Comment: Why not use JavaFX? It has good designed charts which can be used much more easily. The only issue would be to port your current application there. And that's why this comment is just a suggestion, to let you know about JavaFX, in case you're unaware of it.

Answer (score 3):

Try calling plot.setShadowGenerator(null) before you write the chart to the image.  Otherwise, the content of the plot will be drawn to an image, a blur shadow will be generated from that, the two will be overlaid and then the resulting image will be scaled up to the larger size of your PNG output image.  It's hard to say without complete information, but I'd guess that is the likely cause of the blurriness you are reporting.

There is also a RenderingHint you can use to suppress the shadow generation:

```
chart.getRenderingHints().put(JFreeChart.KEY_SUPPRESS_SHADOW_GENERATION, Boolean.TRUE);
```

A final suggestion - have you considered using [JFreeSVG](http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/) to write the chart to SVG format?

Comment: it doesn't affect for me... i've uploaded my new image in my post

Comment: I don't understand why your image is 205x100.  Can you try ChartUtilities.writeScaledChartAsPNG(new FileOutputStream(new File("test.png")), chart, 205, 100, 4, 3); ?  For me, this creates an image file 820x300.

Comment: i need to create that chart in 205*100 only with good quality

Answer (score 3):

Try this, It worked for me :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int scale =3 ; //chart will be rendered at thrice the resolution.
ChartUtilities.writeScaledChartAsPNG(bout, chart, 200, 200, scale, scale);
```

Use scale (int) as no of time you want to improve resolution .